# Apply attributes to links in a class in a div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two different sets of links on a page; one is in an unordered list, the other in a table. I need both to share attributes while having different widths with the links in the table aligned in the middle of each cell. Below is the revelant code I have at the moment.

```
.nav{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.nav a{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}
.nav a:hover{
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    color: white;
}
```

I require the links in the *footer* to be of a different width. Below is what I have tried but it does not work. At the moment the links in the table are 150px wide and are aligned to the left of each cell.

```
#footer.nav a{
    width: 250px;
}
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501379/div-unique-css-style-links) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501379/div-unique-css-style-links) but neither have helped.

Cheers

Comment: the link will never have attribute width .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is missing a additional space between `#footer` and `.nav`. Your code is matching a element with ID `#footer` that *also* has a class of `.nav`. The space indicates, that `.nav` is inside the `#footer`'s element hierarchy.

Comment: Excellent explanation! I'll be sure to remember that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

im not sure i quite understand your issue, but try

```
#footer .nav a{
    width: 250px
}
```

put a space between the `#footer` and `.nav`